# Mod-rewrite rule broken after host upgrade to Apache 2.4

Tags: apache2, php, htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use the following code on my site to remove php extension from links:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It was working fine, but my host GoDaddy upgraded their servers to Apache 2.4 and now all links return 404. How to correct this ?

Comment: Have you enabled the rewrite log in apache to see what it says?

Comment: Where I can find this option in GoDaddy ?

Comment: Oh, are you on their shared hosting?

Comment: Yes - it's shared hosting

Answer (score 1):

You may want to also shut off fastCGI with these in the .htaccess file

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php5
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# To remove www header
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```